# How to run a preview from apload media and add image url to hidden field value in wordpress custom plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have problem with getting image url from media upload wordpress after clicking insert into post. I want to save this url to the value of the hidden field id: "pims-slide-url" and insert in the paragram id "slide-preview"  img tag with the src attribute set to the getted image url of the media uploads.

Excerpt of form:

```
<th>
                    <label for="pims-slide-url">Slide:</label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <a class="button-secondary" id="select-slide-btn">Wybierz slajd z biblioteki mediów</a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="entry[slide_url]" id="pims-slide-url" />
                    <p class="description">To pole jest wymagane</p>
        <p id="slide-preview"></p>
                    </td>

            </tr>
```

and jQuery code is:

```
(function($){




    $(document).ready(function(){


        window.send_to_editor = function(html){

        var img_url = $('img',html).attr('src');
        $('#pims-slide-url').val(img_url);

        tb_remove();


        var $prevImg = $('<img>').attr('src', img_url);

        $('#slide-preview').empty().append($prevImg);
    };








        $('#select-slide-btn').click(function(){
            //Uruchomienie iframe z biblioteką mediów

            var url = 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true&type=image'; 


            tb_show('Wybierz slajd', url, false);

            return false;
        });
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Please help, as I was stuck with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   window.send_to_editor = function(h)
    {
        $('#slide-preview').empty().html(h);
                tb_remove();
                $('#pims-slide-url').val($('#slide-preview img').attr('src'));

}
```

This code is working...